# Using RF Modules with Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: uart, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, radio-transmission

I have 2 Raspberry Pi Picos running MicroPython. I am trying to use a 433 MHz [RF transmitter](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/linx-technologies-inc/TXM-433-LR/613950) on one Pico and a 433 MHz [RF receiver](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/linx-technologies-inc/RXM-433-LR/613947?s=N4IgTCBcDaIEoA0CyBaALAZgygMnEAugL5A) on the other Pico. I am currently using `UART` to transmit and receive data:

```
# Receiver

import os
import machine
from time import sleep

uart = machine.UART(0, 4800)
print(uart)

led = machine.Pin(25, machine.Pin.OUT)

b = None
msg = ""

while True:
    if uart.any():
        b = uart.readline()
        try:
            msg = b.decode('utf-8')
            print(str(msg))
        except:
            print("Failed (" + str(type(b)) + "): " + str(b))
            pass
        
    led.toggle()
    sleep(1)
```

and

```
# Transmitter

import os
import machine
from time import sleep

uart = machine.UART(0, 4800)
print(uart)

led = machine.Pin(25, machine.Pin.OUT)

while True:
    sleep(5)
    led.toggle()
    uart.write('Hello, World!')
```

But the receiver prints stuff like [this](https://github.com/JustMakeStuff-tech/Demo/blob/main/log.txt) even when the transmitter is not transmitting. (I can't paste it here as it messes with the formatting)

As an experiment, I connected the TX on one Pico to the RX of the other pico, and it was able to send the data successfully. Therefore, I believe it is the transmitter and receiver getting interference from other signals.

### **My Question:**

Arduino has libraries for packet radio. (see [this](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/)) Is there anything similar in MicroPython or for the Raspberry Pi Pico?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you got an answer at [MicroPython GitHub Discussions](https://github.com/orgs/micropython/discussions/10313). The modules you link to aren't suitable for directly transmitting and receiving UART serial data.